# full-time to modify a verb such as "study" or "work"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, alternatives

It is thought that people under 18 should be obligated **to full-time study their school subjects**.

I wonder whether the above sentence is grammatically correct and natural because usually I see native English speaker use full-time as adjective not adverb like this: 
**Most children in the UK remain in full-time education until they are at least 16 years old.**

Answer (score 1):

**Full-time** can't act naturally as an adverb in this context although you will hear people speaking of **the need to study full-time**.

To fix your sentence, you need to introduce the phrase **their school subjects** with a preposition.

> ....to full-time study **of** their school subjects.

As soon as you speak of **full-time study**, your listener anticipates that you are using **study** as a noun, and to omit the preposition is simply puzzling.

It is possible to use an adverb in the context you propose, such as:

> ....to intensively study their school subjects

although the adverb fits more naturally at the end of the sentence.